# How to delete data from Json object in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-material

I'm trying to delete the element in Angular JS. When the user click the action button the card view suppose to be deleted but it's not deleted in HTML View but in backend nodejs & DB data has been deleted. When i refresh the element has been deleted all i want is when i click the button the from HTML the card view has to be deleted and also in DB? Pls help me to fix this problem?

HTML View

```
<md-card ng-repeat="user in data"  class="color"   ng-style="user.changeColor"> 
    <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text style="">
            <span class="md-headline">Name:{{user.name}}</span>
            <span class="md-headline">Mobile:{{user.mobile_no}}</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>

    <md-input-container>
      <label>Meter ID</label>
      <input ng-model="meter" required md-maxlength="10" type="text" >
    </md-input-container>

    <md-button class="color1" ng-click="meterID(user,meter)" >
            Action
    </md-button>
</md-card>
```

Angular JS Code

```
.controller('userCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope,$http){
    $scope.test="Hello Raam"
    $scope.meter;

    $http.get('http://localhost:8888/json').success(function(response){
        $scope.data=response;
        console.log($scope.data)
    })

    $scope.meterID=function(user,meter,x){
        console.log("User",user);       
        console.log("Meter",meter)

        user.changeColor={
            "background-color":"green",         
        }
        console.log(user.name);

        $scope.userMeter={          
            name:user.name,
            mobile:user.mobile_no,
            appartment:user.appartment,
            street:user.street,
            city:user.city,
            pincode:user.pincode,
            meterID:meter
        }

        console.log("UserMeter",$scope.userMeter);


            $http.post('http://localhost:8888/meterID',$scope.userMeter).success(function(response){
                console.log("value has been successfully updated");
                $scope.data1=response;
                console.log("$scope.data1",$scope.data1)
            })

            $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/deleteRegisterUser',
                data: user,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
            }).success(function (data, statusText ){
                    console.log("value has been successfully Deleted",data );

                })
            }
})
```

NodeJS:

```
app.delete('/deleteRegisterUser', function(req,res){
            var mob=req.body.mobile_no;
                console.log("deleteRegisterUser : ",mob)
                // res.send(data)
            con.query("DELETE from water_register WHERE mobile_no = ?",mob,function (err,rows){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log("Value has been deleted")
                // res.send(rows);
                 res.redirect('/dashboard');
            })  
    })
```

Comment: I don't see where you are attempting to delete the value from the bound model in the UI...

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing the element from $scope.data, that is the source array from your ng-repeat.

I see that you are not using filters on your ng-repeat, so you have two options:

1. Create one function that receive the index as parameter and removes the correspondent item in the array:

   $scope.remove = function (index) {
       $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
   }

And on you ng-click call that function:

```
<md-button class="color1" ng-click="meterID(user,meter); remove($index)" >
```

2. Simply pass the index as parameter to you meterID function and remove the item from the $scope.data there

Be carefull that passing the index only works if you are not using filters, if you are then you have to pass the object to the remove function instead of the index and use the indexOf:

```
$scope.remove = function (item) {
    $scope.data.splice($scope.data.indexOf(item), 1);
}
```

And call this function passing the item as parameter:

```
 <md-button class="color1" ng-click="meterID(user,meter); remove(user)" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your function `$scope.meterID`

You are calling both update and delete within the same function. Anyways, after you delete the item from your `$scope.data` ,
make another 'http get' call to fetch the updated records list from the backend

```
//after $http.post ( method: DELETE ) ....

$http.get('http://localhost:8888/json').success(function(response){
    $scope.data=response;
    console.log($scope.data)
})
```

Also, in your http.post method, you are seeting the value in $scope.data1 .  What is data1 and where are you using it? I believe it should rather be

```
$scope.data=response;
console.log("$scope.data ",$scope.data)enter code here
```